# MySQL BETWEEN acting weird

Tags: mysql

I run this code:

```
SELECT '2014-05-17 21:59:24' BETWEEN '2014-05-17 22:29:24' AND '2014-05-17 21:29:24'
```

and it returns 0, why?

I essentially tried it with DATETIME columns but that didn't make a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `BETWEEN` statement is backwards.  It should be:

```
BETWEEN '2014-05-17 21:29:24' AND '2014-05-17 22:29:24'
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a million, will accept in 10 min!